# Security concerns with moving temp folder in Windows 7

Tags: security, temporary-files

I'm thinking about moving the Windows 7 temp folders to a different partition to prevent excessive fragmentation. However, my concern is that if I simply change %TEMP%, user specific temporary files will lose their protection against read or write attempts from processes of different users.

Is my concern justified? How do I work around this?

Comment: Well `%temp%` is per user, isn't it? So is your fear justified?

Comment: @Randolf: One does not need `%temp%` to double-click their way into another user's directory.

Comment: I know this is largely unhelpful, but the solution to keeping your OS drive unfragmented is making your OS drive an SSD. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protection is based on standard NTFS access lists. By default, they inherit the ACL from the user profile directory.

- When you create the temp folder, lock it down:

  ```
  icacls "%Temp%" /grant:r %Username%:F
  ```

  (`/grant:r` will replace the existing inherited permissions.)

  Alternatively, right-click on your new temp folder, click *Properties* and open the *Security* tab.
- If you are going to batch-create the folders for all users, make sure you have their ownership right.